# Thread is blocked when to reuse apache httpclient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I used apache httpclient 4.3.4, I want to reuse httpclient instance in work thread, but the thread was blocked when httpclient post data at second time.

```
class SinglePostConnectionThread extends Thread {
    void processResponse(CloseableHttpResponse response) throws Exception{
      try{
          StatusLine sLine = response.getStatusLine();
          switch (sLine.getStatusCode()){
            case 200:{
              break;
            }
            case 204:{
              //HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              //entity.getContent().close();
              System.out.println("No Flight");
              break;
            }
            default:
              System.out.println("Bad response");
          }
        } catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally {
          System.out.println("Close response");
          response.close();
      }

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
      BasicHttpClientConnectionManager basicConnManager =    new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();
      HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

      try {

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(basicConnManager).build();
        int tmpLoop = loopNum;
        while (tmpLoop > 0) {
          HttpPost post = new HttpPost(host);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(toJson(bid), "utf-8");
        post.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        post.setEntity(se);
          processResponse(client.execute(post, context));//blocked when running at second time
          tmpLoop--;
          if (loopNum ==0){
            tmpLoop = 1;
          }
          post.releaseConnection();
          //basicConnManager.;
        }
      } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

It seem that the connections was ran out, but I actually closed all resource.

Answer (score 6):

You can not use a **Simple Connection Manager** in a multi threaded environment, even though this class is thread-safe it ought to be used by one execution thread only.

Extracted from the [Apache HTTP Components tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/index.html)

> **2.3.2. Simple connection manager**
>
> BasicHttpClientConnectionManager is a simple connection manager that
>   maintains only one connection at a time. Even though this class is
>   thread-safe it ought to be used by one execution thread only.
>   BasicHttpClientConnectionManager will make an effort to reuse the
>   connection for subsequent requests with the same route. It will,
>   however, close the existing connection and re-open it for the given
>   route, if the route of the persistent connection does not match that
>   of the connection request. If the connection has been already been
>   allocated, then java.lang.IllegalStateException is thrown.

so, you have use a **Pooling connection manager**

> **2.3.3. Pooling connection manager**
>
> PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager is a more complex implementation
>   that manages a pool of client connections and is able to service
>   connection requests from multiple execution threads. Connections are
>   pooled on a per route basis. A request for a route for which the
>   manager already has a persistent connection available in the pool will
>   be serviced by leasing a connection from the pool rather than creating
>   a brand new connection.
>
> PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager maintains a maximum limit of
>   connections on a per route basis and in total. Per default this
>   implementation will create no more than 2 concurrent connections per
>   given route and no more 20 connections in total. For many real-world
>   applications these limits may prove too constraining, especially if
>   they use HTTP as a transport protocol for their services.

You can take a look at the [Threaded request execution](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java) example

```
package org.apache.http.examples.client;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * An example that performs GETs from multiple threads.
 *
 */
public class ClientMultiThreadedExecution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create an HttpClient with the ThreadSafeClientConnManager.
        // This connection manager must be used if more than one thread will
        // be using the HttpClient.
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        cm.setMaxTotal(100);

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(cm)
                .build();
        try {
            // create an array of URIs to perform GETs on
            String[] urisToGet = {
                "http://hc.apache.org/",
                "http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/",
                "http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/",
            };

            // create a thread for each URI
            GetThread[] threads = new GetThread[urisToGet.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urisToGet[i]);
                threads[i] = new GetThread(httpclient, httpget, i + 1);
            }

            // start the threads
            for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
                threads[j].start();
            }

            // join the threads
            for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
                threads[j].join();
            }

        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A thread that performs a GET.
     */
    static class GetThread extends Thread {

        private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
        private final HttpContext context;
        private final HttpGet httpget;
        private final int id;

        public GetThread(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, HttpGet httpget, int id) {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
            this.context = new BasicHttpContext();
            this.httpget = httpget;
            this.id = id;
        }

        /**
         * Executes the GetMethod and prints some status information.
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println(id + " - about to get something from " + httpget.getURI());
                CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget, context);
                try {
                    System.out.println(id + " - get executed");
                    // get the response body as an array of bytes
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if (entity != null) {
                        byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
                        System.out.println(id + " - " + bytes.length + " bytes read");
                    }
                } finally {
                    response.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(id + " - error: " + e);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager which still blocked thread when use up connections in pool, so I try to use BasicHttpClientConnectionManager. I hope to get a method to release conection to let thread can continue using it to post data.

Comment: I found the cause of blocking. Because NOCONTENT response from server took a body, the connection couldn't be released. It's a big mistake for testing because I just have a environment to test NOCONTENT response.